# count the occurrence of a value in a variable in powershell

Tags: powershell, grouping

I have a simple for loop in powershell
to loop through a json response

```
foreach ($myvar in $response) { 
    $getvalues = $myvar.acc_name
    Write-Host $getvalues
}
```

The output is as follows (each variable in new line on the screen):

```
abc
abc
www
abc
bbb
abc
```

I need add code to count the occurrence of variables and display output as following:

```
abc 4
www 1
bbb 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [the `Group-Object` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.4) to group the values together - the resulting output will reflect the count of each distinct group:

```
PS ~> $strings = -split 'abc abc www abc bbb abc'
PS ~> $strings |Group-Object -NoElement

Count Name
----- ----
    4 abc
    1 bbb
    1 www
```

---

`Group-Object` also accepts calculated values for the comparison:

```
PS ~> $strings = -split 'abc abc www abc bbb abc'
PS ~> $strings |Group-Object {$_[1] <# group only on second letter in each string#> } -NoElement

Count Name
----- ----
    5 b
    1 w
```

Comment: Original output:
abc 
abc 
www 
abc 
bbb 
abc

Added above code. The output is as follows:
1 abc 
1 abc 
1 www 
1 abc 
1 bbb 
1 abc

Comment: @Nisheeth Don't post code or multi-line output in the comments. Describe what the problem is, or update your existing question with relevant details (for example if the input is not actually a list/array of strings as you originally described it)

Comment: @Nisheeth What is `$response`? Sounds like you'll have to explicitly convert the values into strings, eg. `... |Group-Object { "$_" } -NoElement`

Comment: Updated the original post. Actually $response is a json response where I'm looping and printing all the account names one by one. There are many account names that are repeated in the response. So, need a count of it

Comment: Where can we see the json response? :D You just add some new lines with 3 chars.

Comment: @Nisheeth If the strings are stored in an `acc_name` property on each item: `$response |Group-Object acc_name -NoElement` (or `$response |Group-Object {$_.acc_name.Trim()} -NoElement`)

Answer (score 0):

If the input something like this:

```
$test = "abc
abc
www
abc
bbb
abc"
```

You can split it:

```
$lines = $test -split "`n"
```

After it group it:

```
$groupedLines = $lines | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() } | Group-Object | ForEach-Object {
[PSCustomObject]@{
    Count = $_.Count
    Value = $_.Name
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Count Value
----- -----
4 abc
1 bbb
1 www
```

Without the `ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() }` you will get this output:

```
Count Value
----- -----
1 abc
3 abc…
1 bbb…
1 www…
```

Maybe I overcomplicated it a bit :D